# C#: Unhandled Exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Tags: c#, variables, authentication, guid, scalar

I've looked through the similar questions on this subject and found none that could compare closely enough to my own problem. There are a lot of different ways to trigger the same exception.

I'm new to C# and am working on a simple login form which stores user info within a database and then retrieves it upon request.

In debug mode, the line at which the exception is thrown is:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Previous runs didn't throw this error, it was only when I added in a guid or started trying to hash my passwords.

> Further information: 'Must declare the scalar variable "@Userguid".'

I looked this up and once again got different answers, for example some thought it was to do with connection strings and for their correspondents it well could have been - but for me I hadn't had any trouble with the string before so it seemed unlikely.

This is my button click event, the exception is thrown within:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckUserInput();
        CheckPassInput(); 

        //Can we create the account?
        if (canProceedUserPass == true && canProceedPass == true)
        {
            //Add username and password to my SqlDb table 'Users'. 
            Username = NewUsername.Text;
            Password = NewPassword.Password.ToString();
            Guid userGuid = System.Guid.NewGuid();

            string hashedPassword = Security.HashSHA1(Password + userGuid.ToString());

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Users] VALUES (@Username, @Password, @Userguid)", con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Username);
                                                       //HashSHA1 takes a hashed string as a parameter. 
                                                       //Password is effectively replaced by the hash. 
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", Security.HashSHA1(Password));


                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Thank you " + Username);

            var myWindow = new MainWindow();
            myWindow.Show();
            this.Close(); 
        }
    }
```

I'm still trying to fully understand it (its copy code that I've just outfitted to suit my needs).

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query contains `@Userguid` parameter, but you haven't added it into `Parameters` of your SqlCommand.

Since your command text is not a stored procedure call, but a "direct" query - all parameters should be provided explicitly.

Based on your code logic it looks like you should add line

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Userguid", userGuid);
```

But note - `AddWithValue` should not basically be used because it may lead to unexpected results, instead use `Add` with explicit specification of parameter type and set parameter value. See [Can we stop using AddWithValue already](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) article for details.

Comment: Thank you very much, incredibly helpful. I'll make all the suggested changes to my code, particularly the use of Add instead of AddWithValue.

Comment: However I still get the same exception when replacing the Username with userGuid. I haven't tried it with .Add yet, so maybe that's the problem?

Comment: @user3752329 oops... it was my typo in answer probably mislead you. You should not replace username with userguid. Your query contains three parameters: `@Username`, `@Password` and `@Userguid`, so all three parameters should be explicitly set, while in your original code you've set only username and password.